# If two vectors $u$ and $v$ have the same direction, and $\|u\| = \|v\|$, then does this imply that $u = v$?

Tags: vectors

> If two vectors $u$ and $v$ have the same direction, and $\|u\| = \|v\|$, then does this imply that $u = v$?

Well, I arrived at the above when considering the parallelogram law and the triangle inequality. I took it as a given, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Could be $u=-v$.

Comment: I guess I should say "same direction"

Comment: @TobiAlafin How would you define  "same direction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec {u} $ and $\vec {v } $ parallel $\implies \exists \lambda \in\mathbb R  \; :$
$$\vec {u}=\lambda \vec {v} $$

$$\|\vec {u}\|=\|\vec {v}\| \implies |\lambda|=1$$

$$\implies \vec {u}=\pm\vec {v} .$$

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that the vector space is over the field $\mathbb R$, which may not be the case.